# Is it possible to have a media url and a satic url in django

Tags: python, django, django-urls

This is my main urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('base.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

can I have a url pattern for static files as well as a url pattern for media files?. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes** that is is in fact very common, you simply add `static` twice: once for the media and once for the static files:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('base.urls'))
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Django however does *not* serve static files or media files in production: if you set the [**`DEBUG`** setting [Djang-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEBUG) to `False`, then these views will no longer serve data. You need to configure the webserver (like apache, nginx, etc.) to serve the files then.